ChatPromptTemplate Not Working with PyDantic
I used this code with langchain 0.2.8 and it worked fine. I have to move the code to a new environment where I am limited to using langchain 0.1.12.  When I run this code in the new environment, I kept getting an error that:
__init__ takes 1 positional argument but 2 were provided.
The error gets thrown with this line -> propositioning_llm = self.llm.with_structured_output(Sentences).
  

        system_string = """

            [THIS CONTAINS INSTRUCTIONS ABOUT WHAT THE SYSTEM IS SUPPOSED TO DO]

        """


        propositioning_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate([
            ("system", system_string),
            ("human", "Decompose the following: {input}"),
        ])

        class Sentences(BaseModel):
            sentences: list[str]

        propositioning_llm = self.llm.with_structured_output(Sentences)

        propositioning_chain = propositioning_prompt | propositioning_llm

        if len(paragraph.lstrip()) > 5:
            sentences = propositioning_chain.invoke(paragraph)
            returned_list = sentences.sentences

        return returned_list


EDIT: After trying a ton of alternatives last night, it occurred to me that since I am using an enterprise version maybe I could increase the OPEN_API_VERSION variable.  I did that, and now I get this error:
        self, schema: Union[dict, type[BaseModel]], **kwargs: Any
    ) -> Runnable[LanguageModelInput, Union[dict, BaseModel]]:
        """Not implemented on this class."""
        # Implement this on child class if there is a way of steering the model to
        # generate responses that match a given schema.
        raise NotImplementedError()```


do you import the BaseModel from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 or pydantic? Also what is self.llm? Is it ChatOpenAI?

Hi, I import using pydantic.  They said that langchain_core.pydantic_v1 is deprecated, no?  self.llm is our firms enterprise version of ChatOpenAI.  Its an Azure version of ChatOpenAI.
